# C#: Performance issue using locks

Tags: c#, performance, locking

Hello I have an application which save a list of strokes and point with pages. User will update constantly to their devices.

```
List<data> li = null;

lock (locks) {
   li = dataList.ToList();       
} 

var a = li.ToDataListStruct();

blah ....
```

Would this be much efficient than the one below:

```
 lock (locks) {
       var a = li.ToDataListStruct();

        blah ....
    }
```

ToDataListStruct is mapping one object in the list to an type of object and return a new List.

This is a server side. The former one: only locked when calling ToList function and the rest of code using the new list will not be locked. The second one: it locked the whole code.

Is the first one have better performance over the last one

Comment: I would think the first one is _better_ because you spend less time in the `lock()`

Comment: I don't know how efficient ToList is. Inside ToDataListStruct, I have a list of pages and each page I have a list of strokes so there will be a bit of for loop to execute.

Comment: Yes. If you take a look at your two code samples, the first one has `ToList()` but everything else including `blah` is outside the `lock()`. Whereas the second, you have much more code going on inside the block including the common `blah`.  Generally you want to exit the thread lock ASAP particularly if the code no longer requires any data protection

Comment: I'm not sure if it was intentional of you to include the `blah` inside the second `lock()` example?

Comment: Isn´t this obvious? Compare the statements within the first lock with those in the second one. And now ask yourself: what does a lock do? It runs code *sequently*  instead of *in parallel*, doesn´t it? So which one would probably consume more time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The less locking which blocks others is better.

Of course, C# standard library has concurrent collections.

Check out `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace.

```
ConcurrentQueue<data> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<data>();

foreach (data item in queue)
{
    blah...
}
```

Concurrent collections handle locking and versioning for you.